# Traversing multiset from lowerbound

Tags: c++, ordered-set

I want to start with a lower_bound iterator of my target value in a multiset, then delete all its occurrences and continue to move onto next values of the same multiset , I am doing like  ...

```
 multiset<int>s={....};
 auto it=s.lower_bound(target); 
 
 while(it!=s.end()){
  if(s.find(target)!=s.end())
    it=s.erase(target);
  else it++;
}
```

But its giving me error...

```
Line 36: Char 12: error: no viable overloaded '='
        it4=x.erase(99);
        ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:326:12: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'std::set<int, std::less<int>, std::allocator<int>>::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'const std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>' for 1st argument
    struct _Rb_tree_const_iteratorrgument
```

Is there any difference in iterators s.lower_bound(target) and s.erase(target) ?
I specifically need to keep traverse in this way as I know another way to keep finding and deleting the target till it can no more be found in set.

Comment: If you want to erase `target`, just call `s.erase(target);` What you are doing with iterators and `lower_bound` makes no sense. The compiler error is because `s.erase(target);` returns an integer (the count of elements removed), not an interator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik as i said in last , i specifically need to traverse set from first instance of target and keep moving while deleting it.

Comment: Traverse over what? A `std::set` can only contain one instance of any given key. This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), like you've simplified the actual problem too much, to the point where the question doesn't make sense. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , edited with multiset, forgot to write

Comment: If you want to erase all instances of `target` in a `std::multiset`, `s.erase(target)` would do that, and return the number of elements erased; you don't need to traverse. If you want to traverse over all instances of `target`, `s.equal_range(target)` would give you a pair of iterators to traverse over.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::set` can only have a single instance of any value, so calling `erase` once removes all possible instances of that value. No need to call lower_bound first, or anything like that. For example:

```cpp
int main(){
    std::set<int> x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    x.erase(2);
    for (auto const &p : x)
        std::cout << p << " ";    
}
```

Produces:

```
1 3 4 5
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc278318951dfff0)

If you want to store multiple copies of the same value, that would be an `std::multiset` instead. In this case, if you want to remove all copies of a particular value, the most straightforward way is probably to use `std::equal_range`:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::multiset<int> s { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,4, 5, 2, 1, 3};
    auto p = s.equal_range(2);

    s.erase(p.first, p.second);

    for (auto const & v : s)
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
1 1 3 3 4 4 5
```

[<kbd>Live on coliru</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b75e1ca183cd766b)

But you might also note that we still don't really need to specify a range to traverse for this case. We can still just specify the value to be erased, and all instances of it will be erased:

```cpp
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::multiset<int> s { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,4, 5, 2, 1, 3};

    s.erase(2);

    for (auto const & v : s)
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[Same result as above]

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12d966795471e806)

`equal_range` would be useful if (for example) we wanted to erase all but one of the instances of that value in the set. In this case, we could (for example) call `equal_range`, and either increment its `.first` or decrement its `.second`, then call `erase`, erasing all but one of that value.

Comment: edited the question , i needed to traverse multiset

Comment: You can remove all copies from a `multiset` the exact same way you do from a `set` - as in `s.erase(2)`. There's no need to swing through `equal_range`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Yeah, I was just editing to point that out.

Comment: why is error showing in my code?

Comment: @Arsh Re: _"why is error showing in my code?"_ - hard to say since haven't said what error you got, but I suspect that you did a mistake somewhere since the code in this answer is fine as you can see in the demos.